# in sql connecting transaction table with different kinds of transactions

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database

I am making a mysql database for a restaurant.

I have a table called: `*tbl_contents*` which stores all the contents used in the preparation of different menu items.
Now I have to maintain a table for all the expenditures. These expenditures can be "purchasing contents" or some regular expenditure like electricity bill or rent of the restaurant.

How do I store two kinds of expenditures in the same table?

I have the table `tbl_fixed_expanditures` and `tbl_contents`.
If i buy something for the kitchen it is supposed to be stored in `tbl_contents` and if I have paid the electricity bill, it is saved in `tbl_fixed_expenditures`.

[image]

Comment: What's the actual problem? Are you worried about normalization because these two types of items (fixed and variable assets) have different attributes/columns?

Comment: yes, it is about normalization (dont ask me which one :P) but I don't know how to go about it. I have this table expenditures_tranx that needs to save both kinds of expenditures.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question either.  If you want all expenditures in one table but need to differentiate between them, perhaps a flag (contents= y or n) would be the way to go.

Comment: @mikeY but I still have to save the FK of two different tables in one table... do I do it in one column and differentiate it with the flag? or is there a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are essentially trying to represent inheritance in a relational database.

You have two "classes" which are similar in some ways, and different in others. My suggestion is to create a table to act as a parent to both `tbl_expanditures` and `tbl_fixed_expanditures`.

Here's what I would do:

```
+------------------+
| tbl_expenditures |
+------------------+
| id               |
+------------------+

+------------------------+
| tbl_fixed_expenditures |
+------------------------+
| id                     |
| expenditureId          |
| ...                    |
+------------------------+

+---------------------------+
| tbl_variable_expenditures |
+---------------------------+
| id                        |
| expenditureId             |
| ...                       |
+---------------------------+
```

...where `tbl_fixed_expenditures.expenditureId` and `tbl_variable_expenditures.expenditureId` both have a reference to `tbl_expenditures.id`.

This way, when you need to refer to them simply as "expenditures" (for example, in your transaction table), you can reference `tbl_expenditures`, and when you need information that is unique to either fixed or variable expenditures, you can refer to the "child" tables.

This is a very common problem with relational databases, and there are several ways of handling it, each of which have their pros and cons. IBM has a really good article outlining these options, and I highly recommend it for further reading:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ws-mapping-to-rdb/

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's kind of hard to give a proper answer but I can give you some vague conjectures based on what I've understood so far.

If both kinds of expenditures have different attributes but they have a few details in common, you should normalize the tables. use the `expenditures_tranx` as the intermediary table (like, in OO terms, the top-level class) and the remaining tables `tbl_fixed_expanditures` and `tbl_contents` can be the "specialized" tables (again, in OO terms, the ones that will "inherit" the attributes from the parent table) that will store more detailed information about the expenditures. Here's a simple Model Entity Relationship draft to illustrate.

```
   ____________          ___________________        _______________________    
  |tbl_contents|-1----*-| expenditures_tranx|-*---1-|tbl_fixed_expenditures|
  |exp_id:fk___|        |___________________|       |exp_id:fk_____________|
```

Here's an interesting article that explain these concepts:
http://apps.topcoder.com/wiki/display/training/Entity+Relationship+Modeling

Let me know what you think.

Comment: but does that mean table expenditures_tranx will have two FK's? Once from tbl_cnotents and one from tbl_fixed_expenditures?

Comment: If that is the cardinality you are looking for, yes, the middle table will take care of the foreign keys as it will be the entry point for gathering a list of expenditures.

Comment: but this doesn't seem normalized to always have an empty control in a table. I mean if I enter a content expenditure it is going to leave the FK for fixed expenditure empty and vice versa for the reverse case!

Comment: Oops, my bad. It's the other way around, the specialized tables should hold the FKs (expenditure_id), with this scenario in place it's fairly easy to make left/right joins to get all the data you want. Check this post here: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html